# Query tab in SOLR missing

Tags: solr, tabs

I am new to SOLR.  I bought the book SOLR in Action, by Trey Grainger and Timothy Potter.  I then followed step by step - downloaded SOLR-4.7.0 as instructed in the book, unzipped it. Started SOLR on localhost.  Activated collection1.  Posted xml files from the examples directory.  Now I have a problem:
The book says I should see Query tab on the left side.  But I just don't have it.  All I have are OVERVIEW, ANALYSIS, DATA IMPORT, DOCUMENTS, FILES, PING.  I am completely stuck as i cannot follow the book any more.
Any advice appreciated as I am keen to make progress.

Regards
Gopi

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that 4.7.2 has a query tab after using the core selector drop down to pick your core. Note that directly after the ping tab is a plugins/stats tab and then the query tab. Perhaps your screen is too small?

Try going to the following link, where YOUR_IP is the ip of your solr server and YOUR_CORE is the name of your solr core (probably examples). 
http://YOUR_IP:8983/solr/#/YOUR_CORE/query

Answer (score 0):

I feel quite foolish.  But in the interest of not misleading anyone, I would like to report that when I zoomed out my browser, the missing options showed up.  Sorry to have wasted the forum's time.